# Smooth scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

Donec sed odio dui. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.

Comment: Please check your "a.scroll" and you will see that you don't have a proper href...so it's normal that it's not going anywhere.

Comment: @drip not sure what you mean, as the anchors work fine when the smooth scroll code is taken out of the js.

Comment: @Dude all of the code is in the link…

Comment: Look the working example, there the link href points to href="#posters" where #posters is the div#posters, in your case the a.scroll href="#" doesn't point to anything. (opss i was looking at the logo you have them in the nav ok)

Comment: @drip in both nav.desktop-nav and #sections, each link has a valid href anchor that is pointing to other sections, such as section.two with the id of #mission …

Comment: Yep sorry it was my miss. I added the solution as the answer below.

Comment: @JosephBergdoll please check my answer and choose it as best answer if it helped you thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG finally spotted what is the damn problem...

The scroll is not on the body or the html tag, it was on the wrapper...

Change the code like so:

```
$("a.scroll").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.wrapper').animate({
        scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top - $('#header').outerHeight()
    }, 550);
})
```

Comment: okay – I have edited it, but now it scrolls to random locations instead of the anchors…

Answer (score 0):

Drip code it's very good code! but if you have a "**scrolls to random locations**" like Joseph Bergdoll you must delete '#header'and make it empty. **like this**:

```
$("a.scroll").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.wrapper').animate({
        scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top - $('').outerHeight()
    }, 550);
})
```

I just added an anchor `<a id="Page1"></a>` to the place i wont it then the code do scrolling to the position with `$('body').animate` not `$('.wrapper')` because my scroll is in body , This Code are tested in 2-JUN-2016 it's working 100% with Chrome and Fire fox [JQuery Loaded].